# Chrome won't render right padding when the overflow style is set to "auto"

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have the following code :

CSS

```
#div1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto;
}

#div2 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to know is why I can't see the right padding of #div1 in chrome, but I can see bottom padding.
Are the padding-right and padding-bottom have some differences?
And how could I let the chrome render the padding-right correctly?

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Sgzm8/)

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE 06/11/2014**

Thanks to @PradeepPansari for the 'inline-block' solution, it works perfect.
And thanks to @Gaurav for the explanation how scroll bar works.

But it is still confusing me, why when I set display to 'inline-block', @Gaurav 's explanation seems to go wrong.
And when I use chrome to view the demo, the padding-bottom will be rendered.
And again, can anybody explain why the "display: inline-block" works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see FF also gives same result as chrome.

I will try to explain your question by following images

**- The whole process of getting both div and positioning it**

[image]

---

**- Now the watch out the various scroll positions**

[image]

---

> The whole problem is because of the Div 2 height and width is larger than Div 1, 
>   As we know, Padding width and height is not added to the element width and height as it is done for margin. So the scroll get the scroll width and height of the Div 2,  and as the div 2 height and width is greater than Div 1, padding to right and bottom is not visible.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent explanation. But this only explaned how it is rendered in firefox, but not chrome. I can see the padding-bottom in chrome, but can't see the padding-right

Answer (score -1):

Using this code

```
#div1 
{
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
padding: 40px;
background-color: blue;
}

#div2 
{
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP wants to keep the overflow.

Answer (score -2):

You can try below code:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sgzm8/1/)

```
#div1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: auto;
}

#div2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  display:inline-block
}
```

Comment: Could you add some more information on what exactly you did and why it is working (so everybody can understand the problem/solution better)?

Comment: Thank you, this solution solved my problem, but could you tell me why this works?

Comment: Because parent div width 300px and inner div 400px so that is problem.. and if you set same width for inner and outer div then your code will be fine.

Comment: @PradeepPansari thank you for the inline-block trick, but doesn't work for firefox.